# Accessing ACS Token and claim rules not working

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif, acs

**Edit:** I found the solution, look at the end.

I have an ASP.NET Web Role for Azure that I'm currently running with the emulator. I modified the default implementation so that I can use Google and Live ID as Identity Providers. I used the Identity & Access Extension to adapt my Web.Config file.

The problem is that when i access the claims via User as ClaimsPrincipal then I see only the claims from the Identity Provider (e.g. Google). The rule group for my relying party program (defined in ACS Portal) doesn't even have a passthrough rule associated but still i get those claims. On the other side I added a Claim Rule to change the name claim type provided by Google to a custom output value but from code behind I only see the value that comes from Google.

**My Question:**
What do I need to do to be able to issue a token from the issuer (STS) based on the claims of the Identity Provider and how do I access this token from Code?

I'm using:
Visual Studio 2012
.NET Framework 4.5

Parts of my Web.config:

```
<system.web>    
  <authentication mode="None" />    
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
...
</system.web>   
...  
<appSettings>
  <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
  <add key="ida:Issuer" value="https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" />
  <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="ACS" />
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bla" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bla" preCondition="managedHandler" />      
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <audienceUris>
      <add value="http://127.0.0.1:7777/" />
    </audienceUris>
    <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bla">
      <trustedIssuers>
        <add thumbprint="myRelyingPartyThumbprint(from ACS Portal)" name="https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
      </trustedIssuers>
    </issuerNameRegistry>
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://127.0.0.1:7777/" requireHttps="false" />
  </federationConfiguration>
```

The url that is used to redirect users to login page is: "https://mynamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2f127.0.0.1%3a7777%2f"

My test rule lools like this:

[image]

**Solution:** The problem was that I had "http://localhost:7777/" as realm in the ACS but I specified 127.0.0.1 at the Identity & Access tool. When my program requested the ACS in order to choose an Identity Provider a relying party named WebRole11 was automatically created for 127.0.0.1 including pass-through rules. So my custom rules weren't applied because the automatically created Relying Party Application Settings were used instead of mine.